# Win 8, Fiddler, Chrome and Visual Studio 2013

Tags: fiddler

Running Win 8 64 bit + all updates, 
Chrome + all updates, 
Fiddler 4.4.5.9
Visual Studio 2013 + all recent updates.

I can access both URLS http://ipv4.fiddler:8888/ and http://www.localhostisBlocked:8888/ (Response 200)

I make a Web Request to a site and i get an error (502 Bad Gateway). In fiddler i inspect the traffic and notice in XML under Inspector i can see my Web Request sent but the window below looking at XML the response is not listed.

Tried the same on a Win 7, Fiddler 4.4.5.9 (but VS2010) and although i got the same error it was recording traffic in the XML window which is empty on a Win 8.

Searched around but as far as i can tell i have made all necessary changes. Any idea on getting the XML response listed?

Comment: Click on the HTTP/502 response. Go to the RAW response inspector tab at the bottom. What does it contain?

Comment: Its empty - this is where i was hoping to the data

Comment: No, the RAW tab is never completely empty. What are its full contents?